# create and append a span inside multiple div of same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div data-component-id="nwv4kv9j5ct9" class="component-inner-container status-red " data-component-status="major_outage" data-js-hook="" id="nwv4kv9j5ct9">

   <span class="name table-item-name">JHP</span>
   <span class="service-tier table-item-tier"><a href="" target="_blank" 
      onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Tier 2</a></span>
 
   <span class="tooltip-base tool tooltipstered" style="display: none;">?</span>
 
   <span class="component-status table-item-status-childs" title=""><span class="app-status bg- 
      inactive">failing</span></span>
 
   <span class="tool icon-indicator fa fa-times tooltipstered"></span>
 
</div>
<div data-component-id="rtv4kv9j5cyu" class="component-inner-container status-red " data-component-status="major_outage" data-js-hook="" id="nwv4kv9j5ct9">

   <span class="name table-item-name">PHS</span>
   <span class="service-tier table-item-tier"><a href="" target="_blank" 
       onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Tier 2</a></span>
 
   <span class="tooltip-base tool tooltipstered" style="display: none;">?</span>
 
   <span class="component-status table-item-status-childs" title=""><span class="app-status bg-inactive">degrading</span></span>
 
   <span class="tool icon-indicator fa fa-times tooltipstered"></span>
 
</div>
......
......
```

I need to create and append a span tag `<span class="type table-item-type">Type</span>` inside each div with class name `component-inner-container`. It should be after

```
$('.component-inner-container').each(function () {
        var span = $('<span />').attr('className', 'type')
        span.appendTo(".component-inner-container");

    });
```

I'm stuck here and couldn't able to find right approach

Edit : added span should be after for example `<span class="name table-item-name">PHS</span>`

Comment: and the jquery code you're using isn't working? if so is it crashing or anything else?

Comment: it is not working

Comment: did you try using `$('.component-inner-container').append(span);` instead of `span.appendTo("...")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do it this way:

```
$('.component-inner-container').each(function() {
  var span = $('<span />').attr('class', 'type table-item-type').text("Type")
  span.appendTo(this);
});
```

I've changed your `span.appendTo(".component-inner-container");` to `span.appendTo(this)`, since I think you only want one span in each container.

**Demo**

```js
$('.component-inner-container').each(function() {
  var span = $('<span />').attr('class', 'type table-item-type').text("Type")
  span.appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-component-id="nwv4kv9j5ct9" class="component-inner-container status-red " data-component-status="major_outage" data-js-hook="" id="nwv4kv9j5ct9">

  <span class="name table-item-name">JHP</span>
  <span class="service-tier table-item-tier"><a href="" target="_blank" 
      onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Tier 2</a></span>

  <span class="tooltip-base tool tooltipstered" style="display: none;">?</span>

  <span class="component-status table-item-status-childs" title=""><span class="app-status bg- 
      inactive">failing</span></span>

  <span class="tool icon-indicator fa fa-times tooltipstered"></span>

</div>
<div data-component-id="rtv4kv9j5cyu" class="component-inner-container status-red " data-component-status="major_outage" data-js-hook="" id="nwv4kv9j5ct9">

  <span class="name table-item-name">PHS</span>
  <span class="service-tier table-item-tier"><a href="" target="_blank" 
       onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Tier 2</a></span>

  <span class="tooltip-base tool tooltipstered" style="display: none;">?</span>

  <span class="component-status table-item-status-childs" title=""><span class="app-status bg-inactive">degrading</span></span>

  <span class="tool icon-indicator fa fa-times tooltipstered"></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because in your loop you append to *every* `.component-inner-container`. Therefore you end up with N copies in each parent, where N is the length of your loop.

To fix the problem, just call `append()` directly on the jQuery object holding all `.component-inner-container` elements.

Also note that you should use `prop()` when setting the `className` property, and also that it's better to use `addClass()` in either case.

```js
$('.component-inner-container').append($('<span />').addClass('type table-item-type').text('foo'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-component-id="nwv4kv9j5ct9" class="component-inner-container status-red " data-component-status="major_outage" data-js-hook="" id="nwv4kv9j5ct9">
  <span class="name table-item-name">JHP</span>
  <span class="service-tier table-item-tier">
    <a href="" target="_blank" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Tier 2</a>
  </span>
  <span class="tooltip-base tool tooltipstered" style="display: none;">?</span>
  <span class="component-status table-item-status-childs" title="">
    <span class="app-status bg-inactive">failing</span>
  </span>
  <span class="tool icon-indicator fa fa-times tooltipstered"></span>
</div>
<div data-component-id="rtv4kv9j5cyu" class="component-inner-container status-red " data-component-status="major_outage" data-js-hook="" id="nwv4kv9j5ct9">
  <span class="name table-item-name">PHS</span>
  <span class="service-tier table-item-tier">
    <a href="" target="_blank" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Tier 2</a>
  </span>
  <span class="tooltip-base tool tooltipstered" style="display: none;">?</span>
  <span class="component-status table-item-status-childs" title="">
    <span class="app-status bg-inactive">degrading</span>
  </span>
  <span class="tool icon-indicator fa fa-times tooltipstered"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is working fine but how to create the span after a particular span tag, for example in my case after `<span class="name table-item-name">PHS</span>`

Comment: Change the selector: `$('.component-inner-container .table-item-name').after(/* your span here */);`

Comment: it is not working. I did some research on it, but it doesn't work well. Please check my edit. if possible please edit your answer

Comment: It's working in the snippet which is based on the code you provided. I'm not sure what more help I can provide.

Comment: it is working fine but a small tweak should be done.  in the snippet, `foo` should be the second column instead of last

Answer (score 0):

```
$newSpan = $("<span />").addClass("type");
$('.component-inner-container').append($newSpan);
```

It will append the span to all elements with class "component-inner-container".